# Cannot access '/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/': Operation not permitted Spring Boot + My SQL + Docker

Tags: java, mysql, spring, spring-boot, docker

Below mentioned the docker-compos.yml file docker file.

**docker-compose.yml**

```
 version: "3.0"
 services:
  api_service:
    build: .
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 8090:8090
    depends_on:
      - mysql_db
    links:
      - mysql_db:app_db
  mysql_db:
    image: "mysql:8.0"
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 3306:3306
    environment:
      MYSQL_DATABASE: test_db
      MYSQL_USER: user
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: password
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: password
```

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM openjdk:11

EXPOSE 8090

RUN mkdir app

ADD target/test-service-composite-1.0.0.RELEASE.jar /app/test-service-composite.jar

ADD config/application.yml /app/application.yml

ENTRYPOINT ["java","-jar","/app/test-service-composite.jar","--spring.config.location=/app/application.yml"]
```

**application.yml**

```
app:
  name: test-service

server:
  port: 8090

spring:
  datasource:
    url: jdbc:mysql://app_db:3306/test_db
    username: user
    password: password
    initialization-mode: always
  jpa:
    properties:
      hibernate:
        dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL8Dialect
    hibernate:
      ddl-auto: create
```

When I execute the docker-compose up command and service is up without any error. But after start the service below message is appear.

> ls: cannot access '/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/': Operation not permitted

When I execute the container, below error is appear.

> Error response from daemon: Container 11b14cdf51369878501c76085e8fd21316e8a7c26a3ff140196d8674b52c3262 is restarting, wait until the container is running

I checked the docker log and same 'Operation not permitted' issue is appeared.

Please help me to solve this issue. Any help or workaround is really appreciate.

Comment: Which container is producing the error?  (If you delete the Java container entirely, do you get the same error?)  Are there more `volumes:` attached to the database container that you haven't shown?

Comment: The error message is from your mysql container and I suspect you're not showing all your mounts/builds as this is impossible to reproduce on a stock mysql:8.0 container.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in my-sql image which is defined in the docker compose file. Change it to below mentioned image and it's working fine.

```
image: mysql/mysql-server:8.0.27
```